# Vandermonde's identity or other identity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you get from $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{15}\binom{40}{16+k}\binom{40}{15-k}$ to $\binom{80}{31}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ ?
It reminds me of Vandermonde's identity but I'm not sure if that's the right way to approach this expression

Comment: It's half of $\sum_{k=0}^{31}\binom{40}{k}\binom{40}{31-k}$, which is symmetric.

Comment: How is it a half? What are the operations needed to create a sigma that's double of another? I mean why isn't it 30 insread of 31 and $32 + 2k$ instead of $k$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $16+k = u$, then $15-k = 31-u$

Then the identity becomes

$$\sum_{16}^{31} {40\choose u}{40\choose (31-u)} = \sum_{0}^{15} {40\choose u}{40\choose (31-u)}$$

You know that 
$$\sum_{0}^{31} {40\choose u}{40\choose (31-u)} = {(40+40)\choose31}$$

Thus

$\sum_{16}^{31} {40\choose u}{40\choose (31-u)} = \frac{1}{2}{80\choose31}$

And hence the result

Answer (score 2):

Urn $A$ contains $40$  red balls and urn $B$ contains $40$. In how many ways can you take out $31$ of the $80$ balls if they can only be distinghuished on color? This under the extra condition that you want more red balls than blue balls.

The summation formula in your question gives the answer.

You can also ignore at first hand the extra condition and repair that afterwards by dividing the outcome by $2$. Then the outcome is $\binom{80}{31}\times\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks but is there an algebric way?

Comment: Probably yes, but that will be in my view less elegant. I will not involve myself into that. See the comment of @Thomas for that.